# New Line in a prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

I'm aiming for a prompt with a new line.

```
Guess a number:
> __

//instead of

Guess a number: __
```

I'm looking for something to do this, adding a \n in the prompt like below causes the prompt have issues.

```
example = prompt("Guess a number  \n >")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Exactly, as @CertainPerformance said, it appears to have no problem. Could you tell us what happens when you use the `\n`?

Comment: I'm just going through his comment now, in the mean time, when I include \n at that position, when I type a number it acts like im pushing enter, also, everytime you type a key a tabs worth of space is added to the line.

Comment: For more added context, this prompt is within a while loop, until "the correct number is guessed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the position of the `prompt`'s input area from taking up the entire line at the bottom of the popup.

But you can, if you create a proper modal instead. (`prompt` and its cousins are quite user-unfriendly anyway - best to avoid them if possible) Maybe do something like this:

```js
const makePopup = (text, callback) => {
  const modal = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  modal.innerHTML = text + '<input style="margin-left: 20px">';
  const input = modal.children[0];
  input.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      modal.remove();
      callback(input.value);
    }
  });
};

makePopup('foo', (value) => {
  console.log('Got value', value);
});
```

If you want to have multiple popups, it might be easier to make them Promise-based, and then you can `await` each call, to kind of simulate the blocking effects of `prompt`:

```js
const makePopup = (text) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const modal = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    modal.innerHTML = text + '<input style="margin-left: 20px">';
    const input = modal.children[0];
    input.focus();
    input.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        modal.remove();
        resolve(input.value);
      }
    });
  });
};
(async () => {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  let guessedNum;
  do {
    guessedNum = await makePopup('Guess a number 0-4');
  } while (Number(guessedNum) !== num);
  console.log('You Win');
})();
```